# How to create groups of nearby values together in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, grouping

So I have this dataframe in Spark:

df:

```
index           value
1               2.0
3               2.5
4               2.3
6               2.4
7               2.6
15              2.1
16              2.4
17              2.3
18              2.6
20              2.9
...
```

I want to group records with nearby index together. Something like this:

df_grouped:

```
index           value           group
1               2.0             1
3               2.5             1
4               2.3             1
6               2.4             1
7               2.6             1
15              2.1             2
16              2.4             2
17              2.3             2
18              2.6             2
20              2.9             2
...
```

And possibly separate each group into different files.

df_group_1

```
index           value
1               2.0
3               2.5
4               2.3
6               2.4
7               2.6
```

df_group_2

```
index           value
15              2.1
16              2.4
17              2.3
18              2.6
20              2.9
```

The data is separated into many files, 88MB each with more than 700 files, so around 68GB in total size. The rows intended to be one group may exists across several files, i.e. files #1-10 may all have nearby indices, and the index starts to jump in file #11 to indicate a new group.

Is there any way to do this in Spark with Scala?

I've been looking at the K-means clustering method but, if I'm not mistaken, it requires the number of cluster to be specified from the beginning. In this dataframe, we don't know how many cluster we're going to have.

My Spark version is 2.1.0

Comment: Your requirement would bring all the data to one node which is going to be too slow if you have huge amount of big data. Do you really want that?

Comment: He probably doesn't have that big data.

Comment: The data size is around 67GB and is separated into small files (around 90MB of a file). I'll edit this information into the original post, sorry

Comment: Other cluster algorithms exist in the machine learning package